# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, bitbucket

I have a maven project on Bitbucket with and a pipeline configured in order to execute tests after every push.

I'm using a S3 repository for one custom artifact with public permissions I (can download the pom and jar using chrome in "Incognito" mode).

When I execute `mvn clean install` from my computer all works as expected, but from pipeline of Bitbucket I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.2-g4l or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:jar:3.1.2-g4l: Could not transfer artifact com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:pom:3.1.2-g4l from/to g4l-maven-s3-release-repo (s3://g4l-repository/release): Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain -> [Help 1]
```

Why Bitbuclet tries to load AWS Credentials? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved upgrading the maven version from `3.3.3` to `3.5.0`

I've changed the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file in order to use the following docker image: `image: maven:3.5.0`

Not sure what's the problem between **AWS** and **maven 3.3.3** but anyway, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case reason was the m2 directory. We need to include a setting.xml inside m2 directory for removing this issue.